# Optional part of regex expression

Tags: python, regex

I could have 2 types of strings:

- 234_are223422_nextdate_2210.txt
- 234_are223422.txt

and I want a general expression that would return the string even if "_nextdate_2210" is not present in the string. The expression should depend on the keyword "_nextdate" because I do not know precisely the numerical part
I tried something like this:

- `re.search(r'[\w|\w]*?' + '(nextdate[\w|\w]?)'+ '.txt', 234_are223422_nextdate_2210.txt )`
- `re.search(r'[\w|\w]*?' + '?(nextdate[\w|\w])?' + '.txt', 234_are223422_nextdate_2210.txt )`
- `re.search(r'[\w|\w]*?' + '?:(nextdate[\w|\w])' + '.txt', 234_are223422_nextdate_2210.txt )`

I know that might be too easy but I could not manage too find the correct form

Comment: Maybe review the [Stack Overflow `regex` tag info page](/tags/regex/info) for guidance and answers to several beginner FAQs. It's unclear what you hope for `[\w|\w]` to match but it is exactly equivalent to `[\w|]`, i.e. a character class which can match one character which is a "word" character (`\w`) or the literal `|`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIUC you can do optional group `(?:...)?` (note the `?` at the end) ([Regex101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/4o5FrD/1)):

```py
import re

text = """\
234_are223422_nextdate_2210.txt
234_are223422.txt
this_should_not_be_matched.txt"""

for m in re.findall(r"\d+_are\d+(?:_nextdate_\d+)?\.txt", text):
    print(m)
```

Prints:

```
234_are223422_nextdate_2210.txt
234_are223422.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

A similar approach to the existing ones in OP's question is this one:

```py
import re

string1 = "234_are223422.txt"
string2 = "234_are223422_nextdate_2210.txt"

regex = re.compile(r"\w+(?:nextdate\w+)?\.txt")

re.search(regex, string1).group()  # outputs "234_are223422.txt"
re.search(regex, string2).group()  # outputs "234_are223422_nextdate_2210.txt"
```

- `\w+` is very broad. Consider using `\d+_are\d+_?` or similar
- `(?: ...)` is using a non-capturing group, also suitable for `re.find`
- The last `?` will make the whole non-capturing group optional

Some comments to your approaches:

- You don't need to concatenate regex strings. [The verbose flag](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.X) is very helpful. You can even comment your parts of the regex.
- With `[\w|\w]` you maybe want to express `\w` or `\W`. I don't know, it's just a guess. Then, it is easier to write `.` instead, matching everything on a single line.
- A non-greedy match `*?` is not necessary if the part with the *nextdate* is optional.
- With `?:(...)` you maybe wanted to express the non-capturing group. But the syntax is that you have to put the `?:` as first element inside the parenthesis as you can see above in my example.
- Making something optional is done by `?` at the end of an expression. If you apply this on a group like `(...)?`, it makes the whole group optional. If it is applied on a single character like `a?`, it would make the `a` optional. A single letter could also be expressed as a set of characters. `[\w|\w]?` will therefore also recognize only one character (without knowing exactly what you want to gain exactly from this expression).